# Insert binary binary file into DB

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to rewrite this SQL query for Hibernate:

***SQL:***

```
javax.servlet.http.Part file;

                ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES (ID, KNOWLEDGEBASE_ID, FILE_NAME, FILE) "
                    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                ps.setInt(1, obj.number);
                ps.setInt(2, obj.number);
                ps.setString(3, file.getSubmittedFileName());

                InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
                ps.setBinaryStream(4, inputStream, inputStream.available());

                ps.executeUpdate();
```

***Hibernate:***

```
try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();

            Part file = null;

            InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();

            session.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES (ID, KNOWLEDGEBASE_ID, FILE_NAME, FILE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")
            .setParameter(1, "test")    
            .setParameter(2, "test")    
            .setParameter(3, "test")    
            .setBinaryStream(4, inputStream, inputStream.available());
            .executeUpdate();

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }
```

I get error that method setBinaryStream is not found. Do you know what is the correct way to rewrite the code?

Comment: I guess that  `setBinaryStream() ` is deprecated or removed ,as far as i know there is  `setBinary ()` and it is deprecated too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below options

1. Use query2.setBinary(4, ); (This is depricated method)
2. Use setParameter(4, inputStream) or setParameter(4, inputStream, Type )